# Email macro security issue

Tags: excel, outlook, excel-2010, vba

I've switched to a 64-bit laptop and an email macro that I used in Excel 2003 & Outlook 2007 is now failing to work in Excel 2010 & Outlook 2010.

I am getting the error "ActiveX couldn't create object".  I've researched this a lot and can't figure out the solution or cause.  When I go to debug, it highlights the "SecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings = False" line.

```
Errorhandling:
SecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings = False
MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
Resume ExitHere

SecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings = False
End Sub
```

My sense is this is something basic that I've missed.  The two issues are why there is an error and also why the Security Manager won't disable Outlook warnings.  I'm focusing primarily on the Outlook issue.

I've considered a couple of possibilities, including incorrect Excel file extensions.  Should I reprogram it to bypass this error using:

```
goto next
```

Or is this an error someone else has encountered?

Thanks.  I'll be checking this throughout the workday.  I can post more code if desired.

Answer (score 0):

I bielive the issue comes from the [Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) ActiveX component which should be registered on the end user machine. Also make sure that you added a reference to the component in Excel 2010.

See [How To Call a VB ActiveX Server from a VBA Application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/185731?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

Comment: I've added the reference already.  I'll check to figure out if it is registered correctly.  Thank you